# Strange behavior of text becoming clickable and styling changing in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://codepen.io/sodacrunch/pen/VLvEya

When you click "Nutrional Information" or "Ingredients" or "Order", they change in styling.  What is allowing them to be able to be clickable in the first place? I have no javascript or CSS for this to be having this change/effect.

Example of "Ingredients" HTML/CSS

```
<p class="product-info-title">Ingredients</p>

.product-info-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #00703C;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this css, beside the one you posted, the property active here, means that "on click" the css will be changed to the following:

```
.product-info-title:active {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #666 !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Try this http://codepen.io/venu/pen/waKYXp

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your  "p" tag
 wrapped in some "a"  tag?